# Why is my server not echoing or displaying messages?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to set up a messaging application, for a bit of fun, but the server isn't echoing my messages back to the client.

I have 2 files, which I plan to merge into 1 for easier use, those files are client.py and server.py.

My application worked, but then another user said that my server.py could only handle 1 connection, and I intend to make this a theoretically infinite program (minus hardware limitations etc.)

client.py looks like...

```py
## -- Setup -- ##
## Lib
from socket import *
import socket

## Vars
host = input("Host: ") # Host/IP of the server
port = int(input("Port: ")) # Int of the port that the server is listening on

username = input("Username: ")
username = "<" + username + ">"
print(f"Connecting under nick \"{username}\"")

## -- Main -- ##
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Creates socket
clientsocket.connect((host, port)) # Connects to the server

while True: # Sending message loop
    Csend = input("MSG: ") # Input message
    #Csend = f"{username} {Csend}" # Add username to message
    clientsocket.send(Csend.encode()) # Send message to ONLY the server

    print(clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())
```

This is used for connecting to the server, I am concerned about the while loops as they may interfere with my Tkinter GUI (when I set it up later on).

server.py looks like...

```py
## -- Setup -- ##
## Lib
import socket # Import socket module
try:
    import thread
except:
    import threading

## Server
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname() # Get Name
host = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)  # Get IP
port = int(input("What port are you listening on?\n"))


print(f"Server started!\nHost: {host}\nPort: {port}")
print("Waiting for clients...")

serversocket.bind((host, port)) # Bind to the port
serversocket.listen(5) # Now wait for client connection.

## -- Subprograms -- ##
def new_client(clientsocket, address):
    print(f"{address} connected")
    while True:
        Srecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"{address}: \"{msg}\"")
        # CHECKS AND GAMES GO HERE - (game plugins using txt for import dir?)
        clientsocket.sendall(Srecv.encode())
    clientsocket.close()

## -- Main -- ##
while True:
    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept() # Accept incoming connections
    threading.Thread(target = new_client, args = (clientsocket,address))
serversocket.close()
```

The user suggested I use threads to get the server ready for a multi-client connection.

**The goal**
The goal is to have a messaging application that can work cross-connections, right now I am testing it on the same machine (and sometimes localhost), but I want to be able to message my friends who are using different OSes on different connections.

The idea is when a message is sent it uses sendall to echo it back to the original sender and also to pass the message on to every connection.

So, if my code theoretically worked how I intended, my expected output for the client would be

```
<MSG> hello
hello
```

and for the server, it would be...

```
[person address]: hello
```

Comment: So, you mean you want to build something like a chat server? One user sends a message and all other connected users receive it?

Comment: Would using something like MQTT or ZeroMQ be an option?

Comment: @IvanVelichko yeah basically

Comment: @Joe I would rather stick to python sockets

Comment: If your app is supposed to be a professional tool, think about something different. There are frameworks or better protocols for this. If you are just trying to play with sockets, have fun.

Comment: @Joe I'm just playing around with sockets, this will become an app that me and friends might use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something like a chat server, you need to keep track of all the connected clients. Don't be confused by `socket.sendall()` method, it just sends all bytes to the given socket, it has nothing to do with sending data to all the sockets you may have in mind.

I tried to adjust the code a bit to show the rough idea but I haven't tested it:

```
## -- Subprograms -- ##
def new_client(clientsocket, address):
    print(f"{address} connected")
    while True:
        Srecv = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"{address}: \"{msg}\"")
        # CHECKS AND GAMES GO HERE - (game plugins using txt for import dir?)

        # Don't forget error handling!
        for sock in clients.values():
            sock.sendall(Srecv.encode())

    clientsocket.close()
    del clients[address]

clients = {}

## -- Main -- ##
while True:
    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept() # Accept incoming connections
    clients[address] = clientsocket
    threading.Thread(target = new_client, args = (clientsocket,address))
serversocket.close()
```

**P.S.** Please, don't merge client and server in the same file. It's almost always better to decompose things while programming, rather than merge things together.

Comment: It seems to still have the same issues. It must not be calling new_client as it doesn't print what address connected, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I did a bit of searching and it turns out I didn't start the thread, but now I have encountered another issue. The for loop return this error 
"File "Server.py", line 33, in new_client
    sock.sendall(address, Srecv.encode())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sendall'"

I don't understand why it can't send the message along, it has the necessary data to do so, right?

Comment: There is an error in my code. You need to use `.values()` instead of `.items()` while iterating over the dict of `clients`. I updated my answer.